# Initializing an int array with less values then that are declared, will it only add 0 as values?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was reading up on C++, and the site says that if you initialize an int array with less values then declared as such

```
int x[6] = {19, 10, 8};
```

that it replaces the rest of the values with a random number. "In such cases, the compiler assigns random values to the remaining places. Oftentimes, this random value is simply 0."

My question is, could those values be other than 0, even if rare?

Link to site https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/arrays

Comment: AFAIK that site is just wrong.  The remaining values are guaranteed by the standard to be initialized to 0.  I can try to find a reference but someone else can maybe find it faster.

Comment: @NateEldredge I sure hope so - I rely on it in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site is horribly wrong!

(in this point, I don't know the rest, but one has to say it clear ;)

Their example:

> ```
> // store only 3 elements in the array
> int x[6] = {19, 10, 8};
> ```
>
> Here, the array x has a size of 6. However, we have initialized it with only 3 elements.
>
> In such cases, the compiler assigns random values to the remaining places. Oftentimes, this random value is simply 0.

It is really common to find wrong online tutorials, though it is still shocking how wrong they can get even the most basic details.

You can find a correct example when you follow the link at the bottom of this [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) page about arrays in C++ to a [page about array initialization in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) (cppreference is a rather reliable resource, because it is a collaborative effort, errors don't survive for long):

> ```
> int y[5] = {1,2,3}; // y has type int[5] and holds 1,2,3,0,0
> ```

And a bit up on the same page (still C):

> All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are zero-initialized.

The difference in C++ is that the remaining elements are value-initialized (which means `0` for `int`s). You find the relevant part in the C++ standard here (thanks to @Mat for the link): http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.5.

Note that whenever you read that something that has no initializer is getting a "random" value you need to be careful, because thats non-sense. Uninitialized variables never get a random value assigned! If something is uninitialized it is said to have a indeterminate value. Indeterminate values are not random.

**TL;DR**

> My question is, could those values be other than 0, even if in rare?

A compiler does not assign random values to those elements. Why would a compiler do something like that? They are guaranteed to be `0`.

Comment: That reference is for C though, not C++.  I believe C++ is the same but it is a little harder to trace because of all the language about default members and so forth.

Comment: @NateEldrege oh thanks I didnt notice. I'll replace it with the proper C++ ref in a minute

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will mark as solved

Comment: @LighningGaming I have to delete this for some time so I can fix it, as Nate pointed out I picked the wrong link and the one for C++ is slightly different. The answer won't change , but I have to rephrase it a bit

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.5 - the extra elements are value-initialized in C++ (so zero for ints)

Comment: @NateEldredge to my surprise there is no corresponding example on the C++ page. I hope the detour via C is ok