# Why arr isn't initialized into -1 in C?

Tags: c

```
int arr[123] = {-1};
```

I understand that if I do `arr[123] = {-1}`, all elements must be initialized to `-1`, `printf` outputs `0`. I do not know the reason.
Does the compiler automatically change negative numbers to 0?

Therefore, I do `arr[i] = -1` in `for` statement.

Comment: Welcome so SO. "all elements must be initialized to -1" No, that is not how it works. If you provide less values than your array has elements, all remaining elements will be set to 0.

Comment: Your statement only sets the element 0 to the value `-1`. The rest of the array are initialized to the default value `0`. This is part of the language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing an int array with less values then that are declared, will it only add 0 as values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64946230/initializing-an-int-array-with-less-values-then-that-are-declared-will-it-only)

Comment: There is a non-standard C, GNU GCC extension that can be used to initialize several elements to the same value, for example `int arr[123] = { [0 ... 122] = -1, };` will initialize elements indexed 0 to 122 inclusive to `-1` in GCC's C dialect.

Comment: This [explains the reasons why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/629017/645128)...

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that if I do `arr[123] = {-1}`, all elements must be initialized to -1,

That is false.  It initializes the first element to -1, and implicitly initializes the remaining elements to 0.

You'll need to either explicitly initialize all elements, or setg each element to -1 in a loop like you're doing.